# How to use InterruptedException effectively

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception

> Given code is  working in doInBackground(). Where while loop is always true but i don't know how it calls other methods in catch.

Can someone explain me the technique and how can we benefit with this technique. I don't know how and when we get out of the loop.

**doInBackground**

```
    if(isRunning) 
    {
       while (true)  //this loop should run always.
       {
          try 
          {
             Thread.sleep(1L);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException ex) 
          {
            Log.e("Testing Interuption", "error=" + ex.getMessage());
            // some working here is also running 
          }
      } 
  }
```

Can it call any statement after while or not? I mean can it also get out of while loop or not.

**Edit**

When did the Interuption Occur.It means when another AsyncTask is calling Thread.sleep(); it will interupt(means go to catch).  Am I right?

I am calling `Multiple  AsyncTasks` to set a `CameraPreview using Bitmap`.

```
@TargetApi(11)
    public void start()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        {
            executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new Void[0]);
            return;
        }
        execute(new Void[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `while (true)` statement will never end, since there's nothing to break out of the loop, so no, it can not get out of the while loop. (Depends on what's in `// some working here is also running` though.)

The code in the `catch` statement is executed if another thread sends an interrupt to this thread. When the code has been executed under `catch` the `while` loop re-starts again.

If you want to break out of the while loop if an `InterruptedException` is received, add a `break;` statement inside the `catch`.

Comment: See my Edit please. It means when Another instance of AsyncTask call Thread.sleep(); the first instance call interuption. Am i right

Comment: No. The only thing `Thread.sleep()` does is to put a thread to sleep. If another thread is put to sleep while the first one sleeps won't affect the first thread in any way. For the first thread to be interrupted some thread needs to call [Thread#interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) on the thread.

Comment: Then why the interuptionException occur. i want to know when it sould occur and how could i control it.

Comment: I think you need to restate your original question and try to explain what it is you actually want accomplish. This focus on `InterruptedException` seems to be the wrong path forward.

Answer (score 0):

It can call anything, as long as you break out of your loop, like this:

```
if (isRunning) {
  while (true) //this loop should run always.
  {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1L);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Log.e("Testing Interuption", "error=" + ex.getMessage());
      // some working here is also running 
      break; // <--
    }
  }

  doStuffAfterWhileLoop();
}
```

Comment: I want to know when would I get the InterruptedException and  how to handle multiple AsyncTask to do the same job. To set CameraPreview YUVbyte to bitmap and set to CameraPreview continuosly

Answer (score 0):

i wrote some code, which should help you to understand how it is working.

```
public class Test2 {

    boolean doBreakOut = false;

    public Test2() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) // this loop is running while
                // !(doBreakOut == true && isInterrupted()).
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        // this is executed when interrupt() is called.
                        if (doBreakOut) {
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.println(("Testing Interuption -> "
                                + "error=" + ex.getMessage()));
                    }
                }
                System.out
                        .println("did leave loop, threat will shut down now.");
            }
        };
        try {
            Thread threat = new Thread(runnable);
            threat.start();
            // Thread.sleep(x) makes the main thread wait for x milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            threat.interrupt();

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            threat.interrupt();

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            doBreakOut = true;
            threat.interrupt();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test2();
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to know when would I get the InterruptedException and how to handle multiple AsyncTask to do the same job. To set CameraPreview YUVbyte to bitmap and set to CameraPreview continuosly –

Comment: obviously you didnt didnt run my example. you get the Exception when you call interrupt() on the thread where you want to recieve the exception.. if you have multiple AsyncTask you have to call interrupt() on each of them. just iterate through them.